# Polymer: WebComponentsReady or similar event when adding element using innerHTML

Tags: events, polymer, upgrade, element, innerhtml

I'm currently facing a problem when playing around with Polymer - actually I just figured out when I tried in Firefox or IE (11) as in Chrome everything just works as I expected it.

So here is a small demo to reproduce my problem:

The "Webcomponents are ready to use!" box is shown right after the page is loaded (but in fact it doesn't matter because at this time no custom element is on the page yet).

When clicking the `"Insert Polymer"` button the paper-input element is added to the page using `innerHTML` - as soon as the label should be printed (see call to `alertLabel()`) it will print "undefined" (I guess the element has not yet been upgraded). When I click the `"Alert label"` button afterwards it works as expected.

```
    <html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>Test</title>

    <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>

    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-input/paper-input.html">

    <script>
        window.addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', function(){alert('Webcomponents are ready to use!');});
    </script>
</head>
<body unresolved>
<button id="insertelement" onclick="insertPolymerElement();">Insert Polymer</button>
    <button id="button" onclick="alertLabel();">Alert label</button>
    <div id="placeholder"></div>
    <script>
        function insertPolymerElement(){
            document.getElementById('placeholder').innerHTML = '<paper-input id="testinput" label="I\'m the label!"></paper-input>';
            alertLabel();
        }

        function alertLabel(){
            alert(document.getElementById('testinput').label);
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

So the question is: how can I determine when I can interact with the added element? - The WebComponentsReady event is never fired again.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm currently having the exact same issue. Did you ever solve this?